# Which textbook should I study?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, reference-request

I want to study calculus, but I should study highschool math first. Chepters like functions and inequalities. Wording, expression and description in Thomas' calculus and Anton Bivens Davis' early trascendentals books are very good. Could you recommend a high school math textbook as good as above mentioned books. Thanx.

Comment: You could check out the [curriculum](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Store/curriculum.php?) at artofproblemsolving.com.

Answer (score 1):

Larson Calculus is also a very good textbook. There is even a version of it that includes precalculus (Calculus I with Precalculus). I used Larson Calculus for both Calculus AB and BC. The examples are well explained, and the exercises are good practice problems, especially for tests. It is helpful for both the high school and college level calculus courses.